# How to convert [[A, B], [A, C], [A, D]] list into {A: [B, C, D]} dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

Imagine we have a list of lists where the nested list contains two elements [A, B]. Now, you want to convert such list into a dictionary where the first element should be the key and the second element should be its value. For example:

```
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['B', 'B1'], ['B', 'C1'], ['C', 'B2'], ['C', 'C2'], ['C', 'D2']] -->

{'A': ['B', 'C', 'D'], 'B': ['B1', 'C1'], 'C': ['B2', 'C2', 'D2']}
```

The order of the values should be kept.

I have a straightforward solution:

```
lst = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['B', 'B1'], ['C', 'C1']]
dic = {}
for el in lst:
    if dic.get(el[0]) is None:
        dic[el[0]] = [el[1]]
        continue
    dic[el[0]].append(el[1])
```

And an ugly list comprehension solution which is significantly slower because it performs a loop over complete data for each single key.

```
dic = dict([(el[0], [e[1] for r in lst if e[0] == el[0]])
            for el in lst])
```

There should be a better and more elegant way to do this. Can you come up with something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dic = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in lst:
    dic[k].append(v)
```

Comment: come on it's a 100th time duplicate...

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `defaultdict` is to use the [`.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method of a plain `dict`.

```
lst = [
    ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['B', 'B1'],
    ['B', 'C1'], ['C', 'B2'], ['C', 'C2'], ['C', 'D2'],
]

dic = {}
for key, val in lst:
    dic.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
print(dic)
```

**output**

```
{'A': ['B', 'C', 'D'], 'B': ['B1', 'C1'], 'C': ['B2', 'C2', 'D2']}
```

This will preserve the order of the values in all versions of Python, and in Python 3.6+ it will also preserve the order of the keys.

Comment: yes, and it's a duplicate answered many times

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Fair enough. But couldn't you find a good dupe target that uses `.append` instead of `.extend`? Sure, they're similar, but the extend case used in your target is a little more complex than doing a simple append.

Comment: I've seen that a lot of times. It's just that I cannot find the dupes I've seen right now.

Comment: ah found a better one. That said, I like this particular question. It's clear, as opposed to the questions linked. I may not have found the perfect dupe, but there _is_ one :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's tricky to find a good dupe for this. The questions tend to be fairly specific, and while an expert may be able to apply the code from a different question it might not be so easy for a newer coder, so it's easier to just write a fresh answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If all else fails, this one can become the dupe target. :D

Comment: Yeah what the hell. Bookmarked it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be this:

```
l = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'D'], ['B', 'B1'], ['B', 'C1'], ['C', 'B2'], ['C', 'C2'], ['C', 'D2']]

d = dict((elem[0],[]) for elem in l)
for elem in l:
    d[elem[0]].append(elem[1])
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['B', 'C', 'D'], 'B': ['B1', 'C1'], 'C': ['B2', 'C2', 'D2']}
```